# EC2 is down, cant access it over http or ssh

Tags: linux, debian, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

It happened to me several times before, and each time I restarted the server and it replaced the ip and worked.

But why does that happen?
looked at the monitoring tab and cpu and memory were low so no problem on that.

I cant see logs or nothing, 
how can I resolve that and make sure it wont happen??

Just noticed from the image screenshot:

[image]

my node script was killed, but I still don't understand why I can't ssh the server... any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: "Out of memory" seems like a clear explanation of what happened and a pretty good indicator of what you need to do to prevent it in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely because the SSH processes have been killed due to lack of memory.

The quickest way to regain access is to reboot via the AWS console.

As far as the IP address is concerned, public IP addresses are ephemeral.